# Charts - using Mp Chart

Tags: android, android-layout, graph, charts

[image]

I need to draw graph like the image i have uploaded , i am using MP chart library and develop a graph but want to customize it according to my requirement but not able to find solution for my requirements my basic requirement is for x axis i want to show custom values at axis like 5-11  12-18 but i am passing value to x axis like this

```
private ArrayList<String> setXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        xVals.add("10");
        xVals.add("20");
        xVals.add("30");
        xVals.add("30.5");
        xVals.add("40");

        return xVals;
    }
```

So it is showing x values like this 10 20 30 so on so i want my graph to be built upon using these x value which is happening right now but want to show custom value at bottom like 5-11 etc and this value is dynamic coming from Api response so please help me about this , Waiting for positive and early response Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To format the x-axis values, you should use the `setValueFormatter` method which takes a callback interface were you have to implement the `getFormattedValue` method which is called before drawing the x-axis value.

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter((value, axis) -> {
        String res = "";
        try {
            // get current position of x-axis
            int currentPosition = (int) value;
            // check if position between array bounds
            if (currentPosition > -1 && currentPosition < maxSize) {
               // get value from formatted values array
               res = xVals.get(currentPosition);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        return res;
    });
```

Comment: i am using value formatter like this 
  String[] values = new String[] {"5-11","12-18","19-25","26-02"};
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(values));
but its still not working

Comment: Please share your `MyXAxisValueFormatter()` implementation?

Comment: its working now i have done some changes but getting arrayindexbound exception for if x and y axis values are changed. I am sharing the link of full code of class please check the file and tell me whats the issue.  https://files.fm/u/6pdpvfh6#sign_up

Comment: Check the postition before accecing the array:

`if (currentPosition > -1 && currentPosition < maxSize) {              
      return  months[(int) value];
 }`

where max size is the size of the array

Comment: ok let me try and how to get currentposition ? is it array position ?  and have u checked my code from the link ?

Comment: get the current position using `(int) value` and check it before accessing the array